# how to divide sql query result into small parts

Tags: php, sql

i am going to divide a sql query result into two parts. the reason why i want to do this is that i just want my server handle first only 20 items and then after `sleep` the rest part.

how is it possible in sql to part the query into multiple queries after `mysql_query` so that i can process the parts separately one after another?

my vision is this:

```
if(mysql_row_nums($sql)>20){
  handle only 20 items
} else {
  handle all
}
```

thanks for reading.

Comment: Does the SQL `LIMIT` clause do what you want?

Comment: there is a thing called `LIMIT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by setting `limit 0,20` in query

**Limit** is used to limit your MySQL query results to those that fall within a specified range. You can use it to show the first X number of results, or to show a range from X - Y results.

Comment: i just want to query once, and get all query and slit this into 2 parts, so AFTER mysql_query, is it possible?

Comment: when you get array by mysql_fetch_array you can count the number of element in array by [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) than you know the total condition and do something like mohammad ahmad said

Answer (score 1):

Check out the SQL LIMIT argument:
[LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>20){
   $i = 0;
   while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $i++;
        if($i <= 20){
           // do some thing with first 20 result
           var_dump($result);
        }
        if($i == 20){
            // if we have arrived to result #20 stop excuting script for minute
            sleep(60); // 60 = 1 minute ; 
        }
        if($i > 20){

            // continue dealing with result after first 20 result. 
        } 
   }
}
```

Comment: I make some edit, please recheck, i'm trying to explain the code in better way

Comment: thanks, but the thing is that, my goal was to give a pause to server for some time, then continue sending mails, but now i came to know that letting the script ``sleep`` doesnot mean to give a pause, the script is rather still running in this case also, so i solved the problem thru cron job by giving different run times..